# What's the advantage of Stackless Python's microthread than Lua's coroutine in state machine implementation for game?

Tags: python, lua, coroutine, stackless, python-stackless

Are there any advantages to Stackless Python implementation over Lua's coroutines?
What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Stackless Python and tasklets

(I haven't done any programming with Stackless Python, but I have read some of the details about how it is implemented):

###### Pros:

1. Lightweight most of the time.
2. Has scheduler to manage which tasklet get resume next after the current one yields.
3. Support for Preemptive Scheduling.  (i.e. run for X instructions)
4. Channels for communication between tasklets.

###### Cons:

1. Sometimes need C-stack when yielding from a tasklet.  (i.e. when yielding from some C callbacks)

#### Lua 5.1 with plain coroutines:

###### Pros:

1. Lightweight.
2. resume()/yield() functions allow consumer/producer model of communication.

###### Cons:

1. No built-in scheduler.  You have to manage resuming & yielding coroutines.
2. Can't yield from a C function, a metamethod, or an iterator.  (Lua 5.2 will remove most of these restrictions, LuaJIT 1.1 provides lightweight c-stack switching to yield from anywhere)
3. No built-in Preemptive Scheduling support.  (would have to use debug hooks)

#### Lua 5.1 with [ConcurrentLua](http://concurrentlua.luaforge.net/):

###### Pros:

1. Lightweight.
2. Scheduler with cooperative context switching.
3. Has Erlang style of message passing communication between tasks.
4. Support for transparent distributed message passing between nodes.

###### Cons:

1. Can't yield from a C function, a metamethod, or an iterator.  (again most of these restrictions go-away with Lua 5.2 and LuaJIT)
2. No built-in Preemptive Scheduling support.  (would have to use debug hooks)

#### LuaJIT 2.0 Beta with [ConcurrentLua](http://concurrentlua.luaforge.net/):

###### Pros:

1. Lightweight.
2. Scheduler with cooperative context switching.
3. Has Erlang style of message passing communication between tasks.
4. Support for transparent distributed message passing between nodes.
5. Very fast JIT support makes [Lua much faster then Python](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u64/benchmark.php?test=all&lang=luajit&lang2=python3)

###### Cons:

1. Might not be able to yield from a C function right now.  This might be supported in future releases.
2. No built-in Preemptive Scheduling support.  (would have to use debug hooks)